# Python/Pandas Create categorical column based on DateTime values

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, categories

I have a Pandas Dataframe (data) with a column ['Date'] with values like "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS" that I converted into Pandas Datetime format.

`data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])`

**How can I create a new categorical column ['Time'] with categories 'Early', 'Mid-day', 'Late' based on the hour of each day?**

I tried this:

```
def time(x):
    if '03:00:00' < x <= '11:00:00':
        return 'Early'
    elif '11:00:00' < x <= '17:00:00':
        return 'Mid-day'
    return 'Late'

data['Time'] = data['Date'].dt.time.apply(time)
```

But I get this error: " TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.time' "

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: investigate `pd.to_datetime('03:00:00').time < x <= pd.to_datetime('11:00:00').time`

Comment: '03:00:00' is just a string. While it looks like a time to you, to Python isn't just a set of characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html). It is however a bit tricky as you need to convert first your datetime to timedelta:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2022-04-27 01:00:00', '2022-04-27 04:00:00',
                            '2022-04-27 12:00:00', '2022-04-27 17:00:00']})

# define bins and labels
bins = ['00:00:00', '03:00:00', '11:00:00', '17:00:00', '23:59:59']
labels = ['Late', 'Early', 'Mid-Day', 'Late']

# convert to timedelta
s = pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.time.astype(str))
df['time'] = pd.cut(s, bins=pd.to_timedelta(bins), labels=labels, ordered=False)
```

output:

```
                  date     time
0  2022-04-27 01:00:00     Late
1  2022-04-27 04:00:00    Early
2  2022-04-27 12:00:00  Mid-Day
3  2022-04-27 17:00:00  Mid-Day
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just wrapping all of your conditions in your function in a to_datetime() ?

```
def time(x):
    x=pd.to_datetime(x,format='%H:%M:%S')
    if pd.to_datetime('03:00:00') < x <= pd.to_datetime('11:00:00'):
        return 'Early'
    elif pd.to_datetime('11:00:00') < x <= pd.to_datetime('17:00:00'):
        return 'Mid-day'
    return 'Late'

df['Time'] = df['Date'].dt.time.apply(time)
```

Comment: Adding format= '%H:%M:%S' to all cases worked out!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.select` together with the `DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time` functionality to create the labels. `indexer_between_time` returns the array indices where the time is between the provided endpoints, so you need to form the Boolean series from an `in` check with an array the length of the DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('2010-01-01', freq='3H', periods=11)},
                  index=list('ABCDEFGHIJK'))
```

---

```
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date'])
ilocs = np.arange(len(df))

conds = [np.in1d(ilocs, idx.indexer_between_time('03:00:00', '11:00:00', include_start=False, include_end=True)),
         np.in1d(ilocs, idx.indexer_between_time('11:00:00', '17:00:00', include_start=False, include_end=True))]

choices = ['early', 'mid-day']

df['time_of_day'] = np.select(conds, choices, default='late')
```

---

```
                 Date time_of_day
A 2010-01-01 00:00:00        late
B 2010-01-01 03:00:00        late
C 2010-01-01 06:00:00       early
D 2010-01-01 09:00:00       early
E 2010-01-01 12:00:00     mid-day
F 2010-01-01 15:00:00     mid-day
G 2010-01-01 18:00:00        late
H 2010-01-01 21:00:00        late
I 2010-01-02 00:00:00        late
J 2010-01-02 03:00:00        late
K 2010-01-02 06:00:00       early
```